# How do we set ContentRootPath and WebRootPath?

Tags: asp.net-core

We're ending up with the following ContentRoot and WebRoot when we run our app from IIS.

```
ContentRoot:  C:\MyApp\wwwroot
WebRoot:      C:\MyApp\wwwroot\wwwroot
```

Here is how we are setting `ContentRoot` and `WebRoot`.

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnv;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv)
    {
        _hostingEnv = hostingEnv;
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Run(context =>
        {
            // test output
            context.Response.WriteAsync(_hostingEnv.ContentRootPath + "\r\n");
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(_hostingEnv.WebRootPath + "\r\n");
        });
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var contentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var webRoot = Path.Combine(contentRoot, "wwwroot");

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseIISPlatformHandlerUrl()
            .UseContentRoot(contentRoot)  // set content root
            .UseWebRoot(webRoot)          // set web root
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

From intellisense I see that...

- **ContentRootPath** contains the application content files.
- **WebRootPath** contains the web-servable content files.

How do we make the test output look instead like this:

```
ContentRoot:  C:\MyApp\
WebRoot:      C:\MyApp\wwwroot\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RC2, if we put the `web.config` beside `wwwroot` and point IIS at the `MyApp` directory like this...

```
MyApp
  web.config
  wwwroot
```

...the code from the original question outputs this...

```
ContentRoot:  C:\MyApp\
WebRoot:      C:\MyApp\wwwroot\
```

Comment: are you sure web.config should be beside wwwroot and not in wwwroot or inside approot as published? I am still searching for the correct location, because static files are not served once deployed in Azure web app, or .exe is not being executed.

Answer (score 5):

While RC2 documentation is still being prepared, here is what I learned while trying to deploy pre-RC2 app as Azure Web App:

1. There is no Visual Studio tooling yet, so the app must be published and deployed manually over FTP. For publishing, use: `dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ./approot`
2. If connected to Azure over FTP, you will probably see something similar to:

[image]

3. The "approot" folder can be replaced with the published one (the web.config is left in the approot).
4. The "approot" must be configured as a virtual application in Azure Portal (the default was site\wwwroot):

[image]

5. An the last thing to get static files served from the wwwroot folder, the Startup.cs file should be modified to include custom UseWebRoot call:

> ```
> var currentDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
>
> var host = new WebHostBuilder()
>     .UseKestrel()
>     .UseWebRoot(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "..", "wwwroot"))
>     .UseDefaultHostingConfiguration(args)
>     .UseIISIntegration()
>     .UseStartup<Startup>()
>     .Build();
> ```

After these steps you should have ASPNET Core pre-RC2 web app running on Azure.

Comment: Update: for RC2, if the app is being deployed using kudu ("Deployment Source is configured in Azure Portal"), an additional environment variable must be set in Application properties in Azure Portal: SCM_TARGET_PATH with value "..\approot" (without quotes). Otherwise, the app will be deployed to \site\webroot and you will have \site\webroot\webroot