# String Null in ConfigurationBuilder.Build() after Deployment to Azure Service Apps

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy a .NET Core 2.1 application to an Azure Service App. I'm able to run my solution locally successfully, but when I deploy the application out to Azure Service Apps, I begin to get the following error when I call `dotnet /home/site/wwwroot/MyApplication.dll` on the application.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s
   at System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(String s)
   at MyApplication.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyApplication/Startup.cs:line 51
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at MyApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyApplication/Program.cs:line 23
   at MyApplication.Program.<Main>(String[] args)
bash: line 1:  1096 Aborted                 (core dumped) dotnet /home/site/wwwroot/MyApplication/MyApplication.dll
```

This appears that I have a null reference on line 51 of my Startup.cs method, inside the `ConfigureServices` method. This correlates to the line where I build my configuration, using `_configuration = builder.Build()`

```
public IConfiguration _configuration { get; set; }

public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                      .SetBasePath(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath)
                      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                      .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    _configuration = builder.Build();  // this is line 51

    var appSettingsSection = _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
    ...
}
```

Which the only thing that I can think of would be my appsettings.json transformation. In dev, I point to my dev server, in prod, I point to production. So after the build, I have a file transformation set up to make this change.

However, I've pulled the generated appsettings.json from the App Service, inserted it into my local appsettings.json, and it still compiles and runs just fine.

Here's the appsettings.json that is getting deployed. It's the exact same, except for the name of the server and username/password strings.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "SecretKey": "MySecretKey",
    "SuperAdminEmail": "myemail@domain.com"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AuthDatabase": "Server=prod.mydomain.com;Database=Authentication;User Id=myUser;Password=Password1!;TrustServerCertificate=true"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I can't see what would be causing this. I tried deploying this to an AWS Lightsail Ubuntu 18.04 instance to see if that works. I got the same error sometimes, however, after enough tries of killing the service, rebooting the server, and other items, I got it to run for 10 minutes, before it crashed again.

I'm not great with logging, especially on Azure App Services... how can I go about tracking down WHAT string is null, and what I can do to verify that it has any necessary values?

Comment: How are you deploying your application?

Comment: Through Azure Dev Ops CI Pipelines. I use the builtin DotNet commands to Restore/Build/Test/Publish and then save the artifact.

Then, when the artifact is finished, I use the built-in commands to deploy the code to the App Service (and also to SSH the same code up to AWS Lightsail), and then to test, I am trying to manually kick off the service using the dotnet command

Comment: What is the value of '_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath'?

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT the value of _hostingEnvironment.ContentrootPath on the AppService is '/home' -- So it looks like that's my issue! It's not able to read in something due to the contentRootPath being set to the /home path on the AppService. So, how can I update the contentrootPath?

Comment: Refer to this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635003/how-do-we-set-contentrootpath-and-webrootpath and see what kind of changes you need to make in your ContentrootPath and accordingly choose the approach.

Comment: Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes, it resolved my issue. Now I'm running into issues with the application itself, due to how I'm connecting to the database immediately on startup. But your advice got me past the issues I was having here. Thank you!

Comment: I have posted this as an answer, you can mark it as answer to help other folks of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments, the value of `_hostingEnvironment.ContentrootPath` on the AppService is '`/home`' and this is the issue as your application is not able to read something due to the wrong path referred by the AppService.

You can **change your ContentRootPath** by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36635003/how-do-we-set-contentrootpath-and-webrootpath) SO post and accordingly choose the approach as per your requirements.